# What does 0. mean (if (PlotData[i][1] == 0. && i > 0))

Tags: c++, if-statement

Does anybody know what the dot behind the `0` (`0.`) mean  in this expression?

```
if (PlotData[i][1] == 0. && i > 0)
```

Comment: What's the language?

Answer (score 2):

`0` is an integer literal (of type `int`), while `0.` is a floating point literal (of type `double`), it's equivalent to `0.0` or `0e0`.